# How to relate data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am storing a string in a database along with the owners of the string (one or more owners per string).

I've always worked with MySQL which is a conventional relational database. In that case, I would store the string along with a unique id in one table, and then the unique id of the string along with the owners (as multiple records) in a second table.

I could then fetch strings by owners using a SQL Join.

I am now working on a project using MongoDB, and I'm doing the same as above.

Would this be considered the wrong way when working with NoSQL databases? Should I not be thinking in terms of 'relations' when working with NoSQL?

Another way I can think of achieving the same in MongoDB is storing it like this:

```
{
    "string": "foobar",
    "owners": [
        "owner1",
        "owner2",
        "owner3"
    ]
}
```

However, in this case, I'm unsure how I would search for "all strings owned by owner1".

Comment: Please don't use "NoSQL" as an umbrella. You're using MongoDB. That's it. "NoSQL" means *too much and too little* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the correct approach; remember though, it always depends on the totality of your project, what the goals are (performance, flexibility), what queries you intend to run most heavily, if you need to run ad-hoc queries, and other factors.  In general though, using nested documents, as you wrote, is the correct alternative to using joins and foreign keys.

Keep in mind also the [maximum document size](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents#Documents-MaximumDocumentSize) (currently 16MB), which would be a concern if there are many (like, hundreds of thousands) of owners of a given string.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have to worry about the maximum document size as I won't be getting anywhere close to it. My most common query will be inserts. Very, very few finds.

Answer (score 6):

> Would this be considered the wrong way when working with NoSQL databases? Should I not be thinking in terms of 'relations' when working with NoSQL?

There are so many questions on the case of embedding and it comes down to so little.

Somethings that have not been mentioned here that need to be considered if you wish to embed:

- Will the document size be increasing massively? If so then the document might frequently move on disk, this is a bad thing.
- Will the related row have a many join to the collection I am working on (i.e. `video` cannot embed `user`). If this is the case you might get problems when copying redundant data over from the related row into the subdocument, especially on updating that redundant data.
- How will I need to display these results?

Displaying the results is always a key decider in whether or not to embed. If you need to paginated a high number of rows, say 1000, you will need to use the `$slice` operator in either normal querying or the aggregation framework. At 1000 I admit it may be quite fast but sooner or later that in-memory operation will become slower than normal querying (infact it always should be).

If you require complex sorting and displaying of the subdocuments you might wanna split these out and instead have the document structure of:

```
{
    "string": "foobar",
    "owners": [
        ObjectId(),
        ObjectId(),
        ObjectId()
    ]
}
```

I think this may actually be a more performant structure anyway for your data since the `owner` sounds like a `user` row in a `users` collection.

Instead of populating the subdocuments with possibly changing data of the user you can just reference their `_id`. This is pretty kool since you can embed the relationship but at the same time the document will only grow very little which hopefully means a low chance of constant disk movement, not only that but a smaller working set creating a more performant operation overall. Not only that but of course the `_id` of a owner is rarely going to change so the only operations you will need to most likely throw at this subset of data is create and delete.

Getting back to complex sorting and pagination. With this data you can of course get all `owner` ids with a single round trip and then in another round trip you can query for those owners rows within the `users` table with normal querying using an `$in` allowing for the complex display you require.

So this structure overall, I have found, is very performant.

Of course this structure depends on your querying, it might be better to instead house the string id on the user but in this case it doesn't since a user presumably can own many strings as such I would say it is a many->many relationship embedded on the string side.

Hopefully this helps and I haven't gone round in circles,

Answer (score 5):

To complement dbaseman's answer:

Yes, your approach seems ok. You can easily search for "all strings owned by owner1"

```
db.collection.find({owners: 'author1'})
```

This is possible because mongodb treats arrays in a special way.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with embedded data I'd recommend getting to familiar with the Atomicity behaviour in mongo.
A good starting point would be here :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#atomicity

In your specific case when adding/removing a user ObjectId (as recommended by Sammaye) to your "owners" array, you're going to want to use [a findAndModify()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify) operation on the string doc to ensure that when many writes to that document occur, data integrity is still maintained.

Within this operation, I'd recommend using the following operators:

1. When adding an owner, $addToSet to prevent duplicates
2. When removing an owner, $pull

Both are documented here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#update-operators-array